# How to set multiple users for 1 server in Capistrano to run tasks being logged in with different accounts?

Tags: capistrano, roles, capistrano3

I try to run some tasks with different users on 1 server.
The possible solution was to create additional roles like

```
role :root, %w{root@ip}
```

It works but if I run

```
cap stage deploy
```

it fails, as some default tasks are run on root role too , though I need this role for my tasks only.

It there a way to define a role so that default deploy task won't run on this role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old but I found it while Googling the problem so I'll answer for anyone else who finds this question.

To keep something out of release add `no_release: true` as an option. So in your example define the root role like this:

```
role :root, %w{root@ip}, no_release: true
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, beadro. Is it Capistrano 3 syntax?

Comment: Yes it is, although I think it existed in Capistrano 2 as well.